# Is there a workaround for Linux mono's refusal to acknowledge that I have resized the columns of my VirtualMode ListView?

Tags: .net, linux, listview, mono, virtualmode

When I resize a column, it does not redraw the data with the updated alignment.  I've tried Invalidating, Refreshing, and a few other things.  Nothing has worked.  Does anyone know a workaround?  I have not tried this in mono for Windows.

To see what I mean, drop this control on a form, and run it in mono for Linux:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

class MyListView : ListView
{
  private readonly List<ListViewItem> items_ = new List<ListViewItem>();
  public MyListView()
  {
    VirtualMode = true;
    Columns.Add("Col 1");
    Columns.Add("Col 2");
    Columns.Add("Col 3");
    Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { "a", "b", "c" }));
    Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { "a", "b", "c" }));
    Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { "a", "b", "c" }));
    Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { "a", "b", "c" }));
    Add(new ListViewItem(new[] { "a", "b", "c" }));
  }
  protected override void OnRetrieveVirtualItem(RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs e)
  {
    e.Item = items_[e.ItemIndex];
    base.OnRetrieveVirtualItem(e);
  }
  public void Add(ListViewItem item)
  {
    items_.Add(item);
    VirtualListSize = items_.Count;
  }
  protected override void OnDrawColumnHeader(DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
  {
    e.DrawText();
    base.OnDrawColumnHeader(e);
  }
  protected override void OnDrawSubItem(DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
  {
    var text = ((ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem)e.SubItem).Text;
    using (var brush = new SolidBrush(e.SubItem.ForeColor))
    {
      e.Graphics.DrawString(text, Font, brush, e.Bounds);
    }
    base.OnDrawSubItem(e);
  }
  protected override void OnColumnWidthChanged(ColumnWidthChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnColumnWidthChanged(e);
    Invalidate(true); // Nope, that didn't work
    Refresh(); // Nope, that didn't work
  }
}
```

Comment: BTW, I know that code has things wrong with it (like everything in the constructor).  It is only for the purpose of making it easy to test the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  While my method of storing and reusing the ListViewItem instances works fine in Windows, mono prefers that I recreate them in the body of OnRetrieveVirtualItem.